# create csv file on each run

Tags: python-2.7, csv

I've an application which creates csv files in the end to save the result. I want my application to generate different csv files on each run.My application generates the report as below

```
def writeToCSVFile(self,csvFilePath,testResultList):
    #Open a CSV file object
    reportname = "toxedo_report0.csv"
    csvFilObj=open(csvFilePath+reportname,"wb")
    #writing CSV file with the statistical values
    mywritter=csv.writer(csvFilObj)
    for rowVal in testResultList:
        mywritter.writerows(rowVal)
    #Closing the CSV file object
    csvFilObj.close()
```

testResultList is a type list. Is there any way to avoid hard coding the report name? I want to know how to create different report on each run.

```
first run - C:/report/toxedo_report0.csv
            C:/report/toxedo_report1.csv
            C:/report/toxedo_report2.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use an additional argument `counter`:

```
def writeToCSVFile(self,csvFilePath,testResultList, counter):
    #Open a CSV file object
    reportname = "toxedo_report{}.csv".format(counter)
    csvFilObj=open(csvFilePath+reportname,"wb")
    #writing CSV file with the statistical values
    mywritter=csv.writer(csvFilObj)
    for rowVal in testResultList:
        mywritter.writerows(rowVal)
    #Closing the CSV file object
    csvFilObj.close()
```

This is the important line:

```
reportname = "toxedo_report{}.csv".format(counter)
```

The `{}` will be replaced with number in `counter`.

Now call like this:

First run:

```
inst.writeToCSVFile(csvFilePath, testResultList, 0)
```

Second run:

```
inst.writeToCSVFile(csvFilePath, testResultList, 1)
```

Here `inst` is an instance of a class that has the method `writeToCSVFile`.

Comment: Muller Yes it dit. Thank you:)